# Squared fractional sum inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Is it true that $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{k^2}<\dfrac1n?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true. This is because
$$k^2 > k(k-1) \implies \dfrac1{k^2} < \dfrac1{k(k-1)} = \dfrac1{k-1} - \dfrac1k$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^2} < \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac1{k-1} - \dfrac1k \right) = \dfrac1n$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  We can show this by noting that $f(t) = 1/t^2$ is a decreasing function, and that its definite integrals are therefore underestimated by the corresponding right-sided Riemann sum.  Thus, we have
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^ \infty \frac 1{k^2} < 
\sum_{k=n+1}^ \infty \int_{k-1}^k \frac 1{t^2}dt = \int_n^\infty \frac 1{t^2}dt=\frac 1n
$$